# Does Maven need to be installed when we have m2e?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2e

I have installed `m2e` in my *Eclipse Indigo*, through the Eclipse market place.

Do I need to install `maven` explicitly and set the `M2_HOME` environment variable?

Thanks!

Comment: No, but it is frequently very nice to be able to run mvn on your project from the command line too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No and no. m2e has an embedded Maven, but you don't have to use it.

See the [FAQs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_FAQ#What_Maven_version_is_used_by_plugin) about more details, it is called **Maven Embedder**:

> **What Maven version is used by plugin**
>
> Plugin **is not actually using
>   Maven** itself. It is using component that is part of Maven called Maven
>   Embedder. This component is not available for Maven 2.0.x. The
>   Embedder is used by the Maven command line interface (CLI) starting
>   from version 2.1 that includes number of improvements to allow it to
>   actually embed Maven.
>
> The m2eclipse is currently using the Embedder component from **Maven
>   3.0**. If you want to execute particular version of Maven installed elsewhere, you can do so from the Maven launch configuration or select
>   it as default in Maven / Installations preference page.

Answer (score 3):

m2e comes with its own copy of the relevant libraries.

Unless you have a specific requirement for a specific Maven version, you don't need a separate installation.

Answer (score 2):

### NO

m2e is all bundled up. Also, afaik, m2e uses Maven3.